# Alternative to poseAsClass in Mac OS X 10.5 and higher?

Tags: cocoa, deprecated

Apple has deprecated `NSObject`'s [`poseAsClass:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-poseAsClass_) method for OS X v10.5 and above. Is there another way to make class posing work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a class-level equivalent, but you can exchange the implementation of two methods, which was often the purpose of using `poseAsClass:` (of course, you can exchange more than one method if you need to override multiple methods in a class). You want [method_exchangeImplementations](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/method_exchangeImplementations) in the Objective-C 2.0 runtime (`#import objc/runtime.h`). A word of warning: after calling method_exchangeImplementations, calling the 'new' method actually calls the original method definition.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get this to work, using a combination of mcandre's answer and the documentation that you linked to. A quick note: I had to `#include "objc/runtime.h"` in order to use the methods you describe.

Answer (score 7):

[Lap Cat](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/11/25/working-without-a-nib-part-6-working-without-a-xib/) gives an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? There are often ways around posing. I will concede, though, that it is sometimes the only way :)

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of all binding (and unbinding) messages in a Cocoa application. I want to `NSLog()` some debug information whenever a binding is made between one object and another. I ended up using `method_exchangeImplementations` on the binding methods for `NSObject`, and it did the trick.

Comment: Sounds like you're Doing It Right :) I'd be wary of doing it in shipping code.